# Update shopping cart - error when changing quantity of products.. Cakephp 3.8

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cart

Friends, I am trying to update my shopping cart based [on this article](https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/build-a-shopping-cart-with-cakephp-and-jquery-part-2#sec3).

However, I cannot update the "quantity" value separately in the session. The article works with the products registered in the database. I use session. I believe that there is some detail in cart.ctp that is not correct in this transition! I appreciate if anyone can see what's going on!

[cart.ctp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC2zK.png)

The code for my cart.ctp is as follows:

```
  <html>
  <body>
    <main class="mt-1 pt-1">
      <div class="container wow fadeIn">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8 mb-4">
            <div class="card">

              <?php foreach($this->Session->read('carrinho') as $index=>$carrinho): ?>

              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-10">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">product</th>
                          <th scope="col">price</th>
                          <th scope="col">Qte</th>
                          <th scope="col">subtotal</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="row">
                            <?= $carrinho->has('produto') ? $this->Html->link($carrinho->produto->nome_produto, ['controller' => 'Produtos', 'action' => '/', $carrinho->produto->id]) : '' ?>
                          </th>
                          <td>
                            <strong>R$ <?php echo number_format($carrinho->produto->preco, 2, ',', '') ?></strong>
                          </td>
                          <td>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Pedidos',array('id'=>'add-form',
    'url'=>array('controller'=>'pedidos','action'=>'update',$carrinho->produto->id)));?> 
                            <?php 
                            echo $this->Form->control('quantidade',
                            array('type'=>'number', 'label'=>false,'min'=> 1,'size' => 2, 
                            'maxlenght' => 2, 'class'=>'form-control','required' => 'true', 'value'=>$carrinho->quantidade));?> un.

                            <?php echo $this->Form->submit('update',array('class'=>'btn-md text-white waves-effect m-1', 'style' => 'background-color:#1ab394'));?>
                            <?php echo $this->Form->end();?>

                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <strong>
                              R$ <?php 
                              $sub = ($carrinho->produto->preco * $carrinho->quantidade);
                              echo number_format($sub, 2, ',', '');
                              ?>
                            </strong>
                            <?php $total = array(number_format($sub, 2, ',', ''));?>   
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <hr width="40%">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div> 
              <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-8">
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-2 mt-3">
                <?= $this->Html->link(__('Update'), ['action' => 'update']); ?>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 mt-3">
                <?= $this->Html->link(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $index]); ?>
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <br>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
          <form class="card p-2">
            <div class="input-group">
              <?= $this->Html->link(__('Checkout'), ['action' => 'checkout']); ?>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
  </html>
```

cart.php

```
    public function update($productId = null) {
    $session = $this->request->session();
    $carrinho = $session->read('carrinho');
    $quantidade = $this->request->data('quantidade');
    if ($quantidade > 0) {
        $carrinho[$productId] = $quantidade;
        $session->write('carrinho', $carrinho);
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe tell us what error you're getting, and point out which line it's happening on?

Comment: the amount value is null when it comes from the input.
echo $this->Form->input('quantity',..

Comment: There is a *lot* wrong here, I'm sorry to say. The biggest thing would seem to be a serious misunderstanding of how HTML forms work in general, and how input names and posted data are related. Before proposing a solution, we need to know, are you expecting to be able to update a bunch of quantities all at once, or just one at a time?

Comment: One at a time. I made an update to the code. I'm having trouble in foreach: Invalid argument supplied for foreach (). Now I can bring the value of the new quantity but it gives this error in the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Your edit resolves one major issue, which is that you were starting multiple forms inside `td` elements, but not ending them until much later. That would produce invalid HTML. Note that you still have your original `$this->Form->end()` call after the end of the table, that should be removed.

The main problem that you've got here is that your forms have zero information about what row they are supposed to be updating. You need to include some reference to which cart item, presumably either including `$cart->product->id` in the URL, like you have included `$index` in your delete function, or else as a hidden input in the form.

The second problem here is that you seem to think that the posted data is going to have some structure that it's not. You've named your control simply "quantity". That's all that's going to be in the data. You will have `$this->request->data['quantity']`, and it's just a single integer value, not an array you can `foreach` over. Hence that particular error.

And third, you are then trying to access `$this->request->data['Carrinho']['produto_id']`, which very much doesn't exist. Seems like you're trying to get the product ID from here, but (per the first issue above) you've never added that into the form.

So, something like this should resolve it all:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Requests',array('id'=>'add-form',
    'url'=>array('controller'=>'requests','action'=>'update',$cart->product->id)));?>
```

And then later:

```
public function update($productId) {
    // ...
    $carrinho = $session->read('carrinho');
    $quantidade = $this->request->data('quantity');
    if ($quantidade > 0) {
        $carrinho[$productId] = $quantidade;
    }
    // ...
```

Comment: This solved a good part of my problems. Thank you! Something strange happened: Warning (8): Undefined index: product_id [APP / Controller \ OrdersController.php, line 115]. I'll see what may have happened! In the session the value is correct. produto_id: 56

Comment: Oh, shoot. Sorry! I put the product ID in the URL in the first part, but read from the data in the second. I'll update it...

Comment: I tried this way but do not update and also does not display any errors. In the ctp it is: 'product_id' => $ cart-> product-> id, but in the controller the variable that goes by parameter is $ productId. I tried to replace it with $ product_id, but it doesn't work either. I debugged it ($ productId) and it doesn't return anything. Debug ($ product_id) is null.

Comment: Ah yeah, I am mixing different ways of accessing things again. I have updated the form creation line in the answer to correct this. But your response shows another fundamental misunderstanding. Variables don't all exist with the same names in all places. In the view, where you're building your form, you don't have a `$productId` variable. You have a `$cart`, which has a property called `product`, which has a property called `id`. So `$cart->product->id` works, and you would see the correct value in the URL if you looked at the HTML.

Comment: I updated my original code and made corrections to the variables. There is really no $ productId, but it comes by parameter. I'm going to do some tests using the index of the session array.

Comment: In the view template, when you are building the form, there is no `$productId`. But when the URL is `/requests/update/123`, the 123 is passed in the first parameter of your `update` function, and you've named that `$productId`. There is no magic to variable names. You could just as well have `function update($garbage)`, then your `update` function would have the value 123 in a variable called `$garbage`. Once you wrap your head around this, things should get easier for you. Read up on the general concept of "variable scope" to learn more.